# Silverlight 4 Listbox - Programmatically Selecting Multiple Items

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, listbox

I have a Silverlight 4 `ListBox` control with `SelectionMode="Extended"`.  How can I programmatically select multiple items from the code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox.Items.Where(itemsToSelect.Contains))
{
    listBox.SelectedItems.Add(listBoxItem);
}
```